# Setting accessiblityIdentifier on a UITableViewCell's accessoryView when it was created using accessoryType

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessibility

As the title says, I'm trying to set an `accessibilityIdentifier` on the `accessoryView` of a `UITableViewCell`. The issue is that the `accessoryView` is created by setting the `accessoryType` to `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator`. This seems to make the `accessoryView` property of the `UITableViewCell` `nil`, which is expected based off of Apple's documentation.

My question, then, is whether or not it is possible to set an `accessibilityIdentifier` on the view that iOS creates when you set the `accessoryType` on a `UITableViewCell`. When printing the view hierarchy, I see a `UIButton` that is created with the chevron disclosure, but can't find any way to access that view in code.

Any ideas? Is this even possible?